# cursor:pointer and text align

Tags: css

```
<div id="registerb"><div id="rtext">Register</div></div>

#registerb {
    font-size:21px;

}
#rtext {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I want when I point the "Register" text the cursor to change to pointer.But in changes to pointer on the all width of the div.I've tried adding some width to the divs but without result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<div id="registerb"><span id="rtext">Register</span></div>

#registerb {
    font-size:21px;
    text-align:center;

}
#rtext {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width to `#rtext` seems to work as it should.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/skCae/ (border added to `#rtext` for clarity)